# Edifact D16 XML schemas for use in BizTalk 2016

Tags: xml, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2016, edifact

This might be a longshot, but I decided to give it a go anyway. As far as I understand, BizTalk does not include Edifact Schemas after v. 2013 and as such, no schemas for the D16A and D16B formats have been created by Microsoft. The currently released schemas can be found on Github, by following this link: [Microsoft/Integration/BizTalk Server/Schema/EDIFACT/](https://github.com/Microsoft/Integration/tree/master/BizTalk%20Server/Schema/EDIFACT)

Our current solution (which is very sub-optimal) is to change the current D10 schemas to match as closely as possible the D16 specifications for the various document types. Obviously this is prone to a lot of validation errors.

Does anyone know if these schemas have been created by a third party? And if so, where can I find them? So far we managed to find one schema for a single document type created by a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, what you are planning is not *uncommon*.

This has been the solution for odd versions in both EDIFACT and X12 for ever.

Couple things...

1. The specs don't really change that much so modifications aren't too chalenging.
2. You only have to modify what you need to support based on your trading partner agreements.  Meaning, you don't need to add segments that you will not be using.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will keep that in mind. Ok, I will create the map based on the D10A schemas as we have the XSD's for those.